# How to do a time consuming triple combination in C++

Tags: c++, optimization

Is there a faster way to do the following triple combination in C++ rather than doing regular sequential combination element by element?

```
const short n = 1000;
float a[n];⋅
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)⋅
    a[i] = (float)i;

int b = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        for(int m = 0; m<n; m++)
            b += a[i]*a[j]*a[m];

cout<<"b: "<<b<<endl;
```

Comment: Advice 1: build your code with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Well, run it once, remember the result and use a well-named constant instead (that is if n isn't variable).

Comment: You seem to be calculating `a[i]*a[j]` frequently in a place where `i` and `j` don't change.  Your optimizer may or may not notice.

Comment: why do you fill a `float` array with integers when the final result anyhow is an `int`? Simply replace `a[i]`,`a[j]`,`a[m]` with `i`,`j`,`m` and you should get the same result

Comment: Is `a` supposed to be unknown?

Comment: also you can start all loops at 1. Wont save much, but a bit ;)

Comment: The code as it stands takes about 3s with optimization enabled. If you observe something much bigger, you are measuring wrong or did not present a proper [mcve].

Comment: Also, you are invoking undefined behavior by overflowing `b`.

Comment: you could use the fact that currently each term appears multiple times, eg you have `1*2*3` and `2*3*1` and  `3*2*1` and ...

Comment: Consider taking this code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for optimization tips.

Comment: actually I have the feeling that you simplified your code too much. For the code you show here it is not clear why runtime would be of any concern, as 1) the runtime of the code isnt that much and 2) it isnt clear what is the input, the code as shown here has a single result that you need to compute only once

Comment: This code is definitely too simplified.  Is `a` always going to be `{0.0, 1.0, 2.0,...}`  And what is the expected size of `a`?

Comment: yeah. I simplified the code to demonstrate the problem. In reality, a[...] is a list of vectors.  We need to compute the dot.product of the triplet in a data analysis. The sample of triplets need to go through all vectors of the list as shown in the code.  In actual data analysis, we have about a billion of a[..] and the dimension of each a[..] can be 10 thousands. So it's expensive in CPU time.  I'm just wondering if there's a better way than the "3-loop" method.

Comment: Take a look at OMP - probably the easiest way to parallelize a loop. It is not clear what kind of calculations the actual code is doing. You could also move the computations to GPU - harder.

Comment: Move `a[i] * a[j]` to before the `for (int m` loop.  Store into a constant temporary variable.  This will prevent the need to recalculate the value in the inner most loop.  Compilers *may* figure this out as an optimization, but you can always help out the compiler.  This should also help the processor with data cache misses.  With the modification, your last statement would be `b += c * a[m];`, so now the processor only has to consider keeping `a[m]` inside the data cache and not get cache misses when hunting for `a[i]` or `a[j]` which may not be in the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, your sum of products can be simplified to the sum of your array, cubed.

So you can use this instead:

```
// assuming a is an std::vector or similar
b = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
b = b*b*b;
```

You can convince yourself of it by playing around with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::array{2, 3, 5, 7};

    auto sum = 0;
    for (auto i : a) {
        for (auto j : a) {
            for (auto k : a) {
                sum += i*j*k;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << sum << "\n";

    sum = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    std::cout << sum*sum*sum << "\n";
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/361183c54f9362ae)

What your code is computing is essentially the following:

```
sum{i in a}( sum{j in a}( sum{k in a}( i*j*k ) ) )
```

And that simplifies to:

```
sum{i in a}( i*sum{j in a}( j*sum{k in a}(k) ) )
sum{i in a}( i*sum{j in a}(j)*sum{k in a}(k) )
sum{i in a}(i)*sum{j in a}(j)*sum{k in a}(k)
sum{i in a}(i) ^3
```

Comment: Very elegant! And is it correct that this translates to vector arithmetic (like OP specified in the comments)?

Comment: @BenJones  OP said "We need to compute the dot.product of the triplet". I don't know what he means by that since the dot product only takes two vectors. If he means element-wise multiplication, then yes, the same simplification applies (but the result is a vector, not a scalar). If he means scalar triple product, then I don't think it works, but I'm too lazy to confirm.